# Using i18next localization and jquerymobile v1.3.2 in web mobile app NavBar Style is lost

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, html-lists, i18next

Hi im using jqm and i18next. i have successfully applied localization but my NavBar ul li tag style is lost when i apply i18next. i have tried trigger and refresh both doesnt work

Here is my code

html code

```
<div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-inset="true" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <div data-role="navbar" >  
        <ul class="BottomToolbar">  
            <!--  <li><a rel="external" id="amailbox" href="mailbox.html" data-i18n="BottomToolbar.amailbox"   data-icon="jalf-email"    > MailBox </a></li>-->
            <li><a rel="external"  id="afavorites" href="favorites.html" data-i18n="BottomToolbar.afavorites" data-icon="jalf-favorites" > Favorites </a></li>  
            <li><a  rel="external" id="asearch" href="search.html"  data-i18n="BottomToolbar.asearch" data-icon="jalf-search"   > Search </a></li> 
            <li><a  rel="external" id="aphotos" href="AlbumCategory.html"  data-i18n="BottomToolbar.aphotos" data-icon="jalf-photos"   > Photos </a></li> 
            <li><a  rel="external" id="alocation" href="location.html"  data-i18n="BottomToolbar.alocation" data-icon="jalf-location" > Location </a></li> 
        </ul>  
    </div> 
</div>
```

here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UAYxg/3/)

Comment: `$(".BottomToolbar .ui-btn-text")` as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery 1.4.2 I've fixed it like this:

```
<div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-inset="true" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <div data-role="navbar" > 
        <ul class="BottomToolbar"> 
            <!-- <li><a rel="external" id="amailbox" href="mailbox.html"  data-icon="jalf-email"><span data-i18n="BottomToolbar.amailbox"></span</a></li>-->
            <li><a rel="external" id="afavorites" href="favorites.html" data-icon="jalf-favorites"><span data-i18n="BottomToolbar.afavorites"></span></a></li> 
            <li><a rel="external" id="asearch" href="search.html" data-icon="jalf-search"><span data-i18n="BottomToolbar.asearch"></span></a></li> 
            <li><a rel="external" id="aphotos" href="AlbumCategory.html" data-icon="jalf-photos"><span data-i18n="BottomToolbar.aphotos"></span></a></li> 
            <li><a rel="external" id="alocation" href="location.html" data-icon="jalf-location"><span data-i18n="BottomToolbar.alocation"></span></a></li> 
        </ul> 
    </div> 
</div>
```